# Is voter turnout connected to dissatisfaction?

Tags: political-theory, reference-request, voter-turnout, demographics, political-science

Is there a study revealing a connection between voter turnout and the level of dissatisfaction with the political situation?

Comment: it's easy to plot "right track/wrong track" surveys to turnout; both are well-documented. i'd be interested in the results.

Answer (score 5):

This question appears a bit too broad, so my answer will be brief since I don't want to get into the details of each possible interpretation of "level of dissatisfaction with the political situation".

Basically if "level of dissatisfaction with the political situation" means "legitimacy deficit", or "dissatisfaction with democracy", that's one line of research... and the results appear mixed. E.g. [one study](https://ecpr.eu/Filestore/PaperProposal/d83ddd59-0a00-4535-a117-55a859e6a630.pdf) on EU countries finds in favor of that hypothesis:

> We have seen that turnout is the lowest among the voters who have no trust in the system and
> its actors. At the aggregate level, there is also a clear and linear relationship between the
> aspects of democratic legitimacy and turnout. Countries whose citizens are distrustful of the
> parliament and politicians as well as dissatisfied with the way democracy works have lower
> turnout than countries, whose citizens are trustful.

But [another study](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1354068814549335) says...

> Numerous studies conclude that countries in which citizens express higher levels of satisfaction with democracy also tend to display higher levels of voter turnout in national elections. [...] We apply an alternative, temporal approach to this issue by asking the question: Are over-time declines (increases) in aggregate levels of satisfaction within democracies associated with increases (declines) in levels of voter turnout within these democracies? Our temporal analysis of this relationship in 12 democracies over the period 1976–2011 reveals a pattern that is the opposite of that suggested by previous cross-sectional studies: namely, we find that over-time increases in citizens’ satisfaction with democracy are associated with significant decreases in voter turnout in national elections in these countries.

So cross-sectional and temporal data don't seem to quite agree on this insofar (although the majority of studies are of the former kind).

---

If "dissatisfaction with the political situation" means some general or specific anti-incumbency discontent... the results are also pretty mixed, at least in India, where I could find [a study](https://carnegieendowment.org/2018/05/07/is-higher-turnout-bad-for-incumbents-pub-76238) on this (seemingly less researched topic):

> What our analyses do reveal is that, despite the popularity of the notion that citizens come out to the polls in greater numbers when they are motivated to punish the incumbent government, three decades of electoral data present a more ambiguous picture. Voter turnout, the data suggest, is not necessarily pro- or anti-incumbent; rather, the relationship between these two variables is likely shaped by the specific context at hand. Similar analyses using national election data conducted by other researchers tell a comparable story: changes in voter turnout are not highly informative of future electoral outcomes.
>
> So why does this popular trope get repeated election after election? For starters, there are several cases where higher turnout does coincide with poor incumbent performance. Nearly every election expert can point to this or that anecdote to prove her point. Second, focusing on changes in turnout feeds pre-election chatter and punditry during the seemingly interminable period between the time votes are cast and ballots are counted. Third and finally, the idea that higher turnout reflects voter disenchantment intuitively “feels” right: after all, why would voters who previously stayed home show up, other than vote a particularly bad incumbent out? Unfortunately, hard election data leaves these explanations wanting.

[Another paper](https://faculty.ucmerced.edu/jtrounstine/low_turnout_UAR_RR.pdf) about US local elections draws somewhat different conclusions, namely that low turnout does predict re-election at least in city council elections, but this is apparently mediated by institutional arrangements:

> It is well established that incumbents win reelection at high rates. But we know less about the
> ways in which institutional variation affects the incumbency advantage. Using data from more
> than 4,000 cities evidence in this paper indicates that institutions which generate low participation environments increase the proportion of city council incumbents who run for
> reelection and the proportion who win. These low-turnout environments are shown to have
> spending patterns that benefit particular subgroups in the population who have good reason to
> participate even when the costs are high.

Answer (score 0):

There are theories on this subject, but not a lot of research, since it's a particularly difficult topic to operationalize for proper study. The problem is that there is a strong, subjective, emotional component to turnout. An individual's likelihood to vote is affected by both specific and generalized fears, frustrations with the system, angers and resentments, senses of shame or outrage, or other affective elements.  The first step in casting a vote is acquiring the motivation to cast a vote, and a lot of modern politics aims at generating or destroying that initial motivation.

For example, one of the reasons that US (and increasingly, world) politics tends to de-evolve to brutal, negative attacks and offensive social media memes is that political parties have caught on to the primary effects of virulent messaging:

- It offends and puts off moderate, thoughtful voters — the ones who generally act as undependable swing votes — increasing their sense of cynicism and frustration and reducing their likelihood to vote.
- It titillates and emboldens extremely partisan voters — the ones who can be counted on to vote consistently party line or for particular issues — increasing their likelihood to vote.

Reducing the number of unpredictable votes in this fashion makes it easier to predict outcomes in specific districts, and thus makes it easier to know which districts to allocate limited resources to, maximizing the effect of those resources. This kind of statistical bet-hedging lies behind many efforts in US politics, from gerrymandering to voter suppression to removing voting rights from felons; parties care less about gathering a greater amount of voted than about limiting votes to those they know they can gather for themselves.

In this sense, 'dissatisfaction' is too ambiguous a word to be useful. Dissatisfaction tuned one way with the appropriate messaging can boil into anger that can be leveraged for partisan advantage. We often see this with 'fear of loss' type messaging, where the opposition is painted as wanting to remove a liberty, privilege, or assumed right, so that people will become angry and be motivated to cast a vote for the ostensible *defenders*, i.e., the party that initiated the negative messaging. Dissatisfaction tuned another way, with different messaging, can generate frustration, cynicism, or shame, which can drive people away from the polls. Arguably, the impeachment of Clinton in the 90's created dissatisfaction that turned into shame and lowered Democratic turnout in the 2000 election; the housing bubble crash and collapse of of the economy at the end of GW Bush's administration demoralized Republican voters, which contributed to Obama's victory in 2008.

Obviously, this kind of emotional manipulation is destructive to civil discourse and democratic institutions. The current political polarization we see in the US is (I'd argue) a direct result of intense efforts at negative messaging amplified by partisan-affiliated media sources. It's something we should all be aware of so that we are not caught in this drive to establish emotional reasoning as the norm in politics.